# Creating folder in internal memory in android

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, directory

I want to create a folder in the root of internal memory in Android. I'm using the following code to do so:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path.toString() + "/" + "folder name"
```

or

```
val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder name")
```

It works in some devices or emulators, but not all of them, so I am confused. Can anyone tell me what is happening?

(The issue is not dependent on Android API level).

Comment: Use `context.getFilesDir()` for internal storage.

Comment: That does not work in Android Q but you did not mention. Moreover you did not show code that tries to create a directory.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? If not, check here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage